# UIButton keep content on top of backgroundImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have a UIButton and I'm setting a background image on it:

```
[self.button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button-background"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I want the content of the button to stay on top of the background image, and not be affected by it. So when the button content is text, the font color of the text would be unaffected by changing the background image. I'd like it to behave similarly when the button content is an image.

What's the best way to achieve this behavior?

Comment: When you set a `backgroundImage` on a `UIButton`, it always appears below other content (unless you do something shifty like insert a subview below all other subviews of your UIButton). Can you explain in more detail why you believe your background image isn't staying below the rest of the button content?

Comment: @IanMacDonald I think I was experiencing an optical illusion and my content wasn't actually changing. And then in another case I think I had a transparent image. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the background of the button does exactly what you're asking. However, make sure your button is in the state you're setting the background image for. Text will appear over this image based on your settings.

```
forState:UIControlStateNormal (Highlighted, selected, etc)
```